# www redirect issue with subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, cdn

Please forgive any blatant mistakes as I am a newbie.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is what I have in my htaccess file. I want to redirect my non-www to www.

Now I have to add a new subdomain for CDN files called media but the issue is that above code redirects media.mywebsite.com.au to www.media.mywebsite.com.au as well.

How can I fix this? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com.au$` instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.`?

Comment: yea I know there is some duplication? would that solve the issue with subdomains?

Comment: This would say “only rewrite when the hostname is `mywebsite.com.au`”, rather than “rewrite whenever the hostname doesn’t start with `www.`”.

Comment: So this would be the final code:  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com.au$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]`